# Could not install openpyx1 in window 10

Tags: python-3.x

When I tried to install

```
pip install openpyx1
```

in Windows 10, I got

> Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyx1

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install openpyx1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyx1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openpyx1

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version
pip 22.2.2 from C:\Users\n1122332\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Comment: It's **openpyxl**, not **openpyx1**. It's the lowercase letter **l**, not the number **1**.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a typo where you put then number `1` insead of letter `l`.

```py
a = 'openpyx1' 
b = 'openpyxl'

if a==b:
    print('same')
else:
    print('different')
```

returns:

```
different
```

Comment: Many thank. problem solved, it is my typo. it should be l, but I type as 1. Regards